# Drupal 7: Translate Taxonomy menu items

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-taxonomy

I'm quite stucked with a problem with Taxonomy menu. I have a vocabulary that I want to shows as a menu. For this, I installed the taxonomy menu module and edit the vocabulary to hang from a menu item of Main Menu. The menu shows perfectly.

The problem goes when I localize the terms of vocabulary, the menu it's only shown in the default language. I tried to rebuild the menu (by checking the "Select to rebuild the menu on submit." on vocabulary edit page and submiting), but the problem persists.

I'm trying to fix this for 2 days, I searched for a solution, but nothing found.

I hope someone could give me some solution, or suggest another way to do this.

Thanks, and sorry for my english.

Comment: did you find a solution for this problem?

Answer (score -3):

drag the module into your favorite editor then locate this `fxrefresh->true, $taxonomy ($row['rebb']);` after that change that into `fxrefresh->false, $taxonomy(',,$row['rebb']);` and add this below `$taxonomy->$taxonomy(,, refresh, 'CHECK', true_);`

Comment: I looked for this code in "taxonomy_menu" module, and the word "fxrefresh" in all files of my drupal installation, but there aren't any occurrences. Thanks for the answer, but if you could be more specific, I will appreciate it.

Comment: right, the code above doesn't make any sense. are you talking about Drupal module here?